# Will delaying loading Google reCAPTCHA JS until form submission result in more challenges?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, grecaptcha

I'm implementing Invisible reCAPTCHA on my website, and to reduce the number of third party JS files on page load I'd like to download the `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js` file only once the user submits a form. Once it loads I would then use `grecaptcha.render` followed by `grecaptcha.execute`. I've implemented and tested this, and it works as expected.

My concern is that delaying this file load may negatively affect Google's ability to confirm the user is not a robot. For example, perhaps Google's JS picks up user events while they're using the page and uses those actions to verify the humanness of a user. By delaying the JS load, Google won't have those user events to take into account and may result in more legitimate users getting annoying image challenges.

[The docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) don't mention anything about this. Does anyone have experience with this implementation? I'd think Google relies on other info like IP address and cookies for this kind of verification, but I want to confirm.

Comment: Do you got any solution ?

Comment: @iamabs2001 unfortunately I don't remember what I did in the end :)